# Is there always a ".next()" element?

Tags: jquery

I'm running this code. My markup is a bunch of DIVs classed as *alternative* and only one is *active*.

```
var currentTag = $(".alternative.active");
currentTag.removeClass("active");

if (event.which === 38 && currentTag.prev(".alternative").length !== 0)
  currentTag.prev(".alternative").addClass("active");

if (event.which === 40 && currentTag.next(".alternative").length !== 0)
  currentTag.next(".alternative").addClass("active");
```

This works great except that when I get to the last element, it starts from the top. But when I come to the top most element, it behaves as expected - no action is taken. Is there a logic problem in my code? Are *next* elements recursive somehow?

Comment: Post your HTML and a jsFiddle please.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `currentTag.next(".alternative")` indeed returns elements? And which elements are they?

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm doing the check in the *if* statement so that the length isn't zero. As for the type, I only set the class *alternative* to these elements, so I'd say that it's ensured. What more can I check?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I added an answer. Please check it and comment if it is what you needed (or, if it isn't, the expected behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to keep a `div` `.active` at all times. So only remove the class (`currentTag.removeClass("active")`) when there is an acceptable next (or previous) activable:

```
var currentTag = $(".alternative.active");

if (event.which === 38 && currentTag.prev(".alternative").length !== 0) {
    currentTag.removeClass("active").prev(".alternative").addClass("active");
}
if (event.which === 40 && currentTag.next(".alternative").length !== 0) {
    currentTag.removeClass("active").next(".alternative").addClass("active");
}
```

[See demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/JwxMR/3/)

Comment: Oh, this was a nasty one. Actually, when I cut the code to make the example smooth to your eyes, I baked in a new error. You've resolved it. Also, when I was correcting the new error I realized what the problem was. It's a business logic error, so kudos to you for help without realizing the second issue.   :)

Comment: Aw, great, then! Just revisiting the title: ***Is there always a “next” element but not “prev”?***, we can see in the demo fiddle, none of them *always* exist. Did this make sense?

Comment: Yes. Helpful and clear. Thanks. Enjoy the reputation increment.   :)